# Rooted Karbonn Smart A26 not powering up after mistakenly deleted one file from boot

Tags: root-access, 4.1-jelly-bean, unbricking, karbonn

I have a Karbonn Smart A26 on Android 4.1.1. After rooting and using it for 3 years, I mistakenly deleted one file from boot. Now it's not powering up.

I gave it to the service centre, and they told me it was a waste and threw it. I still have the ROM and tried flashing it, but it's not responding. The light switches on, it powers up, but won't connect.

Anyone, please tell me how to recover that "bricked" phone.

Comment: You've likely corrupted the bootloader. I'm not familiar enough with this device to have the confidence to post this as an answer, but your phone's probably done.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Download a custom ROM for your mobile model.
2. Android flashing application
3. Download device drivers.
4. Now flash the mobile by connecting a USB cable to your system.
5. Run the application and then you have successfully flashed your mobile.